# Trouble in swapping and assignment min and max elements

Tags: python, debugging, indexing

IMPORTANT UPD AT THE END!
The existing code works not for all cases.

```
def myfunc(x):
    a = [int(i) for i in x.split()]
    a[a.index(min(a))], a[a.index(max(a))] = a[a.index(max(a))], a[a.index(min(a))]
    a = [str(i) for i in a]
    return ' '.join(a)

myfunc()
```

It works for 3 4 5 2 1 and don't work for 1 5 4 3 2.
Why?

!!!UPD: I made some changes and it looks very strange.
I used two different lines separately (with commented one of them). The program gives different results in some cases. BUT THE MOST INTERESTING, when I used two of them, uncommented - the program don't return the income string?

```
#    a[a.index(min(a))], a[a.index(max(a))] = a[a.index(max(a))], a[a.index(min(a))]
    a[a.index(max(a))], a[a.index(min(a))] = a[a.index(min(a))], a[a.index(max(a))]
```

Cases which I use:

```
#print(myfunc("5 1 4 3 2"))
#print(myfunc("1 5 4 3 2"))
#print(myfunc("3 4 5 2 1"))
#print(myfunc("-30000 30000"))
#print(myfunc("2147483647 -2147483648"))
#print(myfunc("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 17 16 15 14"))
#print(myfunc("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"))
#print(myfunc("1 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 10"))
```

UPD+=1   Guys I changed code to:

```
    minind = a.index(min(a))
    maxind = a.index(max(a))
    a[minind], a[maxind] = a[maxind], a[minind]
```

Now it works for all case. But question about previous cases are still open
Please help. I spend about 2 hours in tries to find some explanation of this...
Please help

Comment: What's the desired output exactly?

Comment: what does "not work" mean, **exactly**. What is `myfunc` supposed to do?

Comment: The code you show basically swaps the maximum and the minimum integer. It worked for me in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it doesn't work is because the assignments are being executed sequentially. When you write:

```
a[a.index(min(a))], a[a.index(max(a))] = a[a.index(max(a))], a[a.index(min(a))]
```

it's essentially equivalent to:

```
tempmax, tempmin = a[a.index(max(a))], a[a.index(min(a))]
a[a.index(min(a))] = tempmax
a[a.index(max(a))] = tempmin
```

But notice that after doing the `tempmax` assignment, `a.index(max(a))` can change. `index()` returns the earliest index, so if the minimum element was before the maximum element, this will now return the original minimum element's location (because it now contains the maximum element), and assigns `tempmin` back to it.

Your code assumes that the indexes to be assigned are computed before any of the assignments are done, but that's not how it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work if the minimum is located before the maximum.

For example:

```
s = "1 5 4 3 2"  # this doesn't work
myfunc(s)

>>> '1 5 4 3 2'

s = "5 1 4 3 2"  # this works
myfunc(s)

>>> '1 5 4 3 2'
```

But, as you noticed, if you define indices before swapping, everything works fine.

```
def myfunc(x):
    a = [int(i) for i in x.split()]
    mn = a.index(min(a))
    mx = a.index(max(a))
    a[mn], a[mx] = a[mx], a[mn]
    a = [str(i) for i in a]
    return ' '.join(a)

s = "1 5 4 3 2"
myfunc(s)

>>> '5 1 4 3 2'
```

I'm waiting for some illuminati mind to have an answer for this.